# Stripe, on reload page customer is charged again

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have created a table `app__stripe_customer` containing customers id in order to avoid creating multiple times a same customer.

```
if ($_POST) {

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($StripeKeySecret);
    $error = '';
    $success = '';

    /**
     * Check if Customer Exists if not Create a Customer:
     */
    try {
        $sql = $dataBase->prepare('SELECT * FROM app__stripe_customer
                                   WHERE user_id = :uid');
        $sql->execute(array('uid'  => $_SESSION['user_id']));
        $stripeCustomer = $sql->fetch();
        if(empty($stripeCustomer)) {
            /**
             *  We create the new Stripe Customer
             */
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "email" => $user['email'],
                "source" => $token));

            /**
             *  Creating new Stripe Customer Id in database
             */
            $sql = $dataBase->prepare('INSERT INTO app__stripe_customer(user_id, customer_id)
                                       VALUES(:uid, 
                                              :cid)');
            $sql->execute(array('uid'  => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                                'cid'  => $customer->id));
            $stripeCustomerId = $customer->id;
        } else {
            $stripeCustomerId = $stripeCustomer['customer_id'];
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
            throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array("amount" => $AMT*100,
                                               "currency" => "usd",
                                               "customer" => $stripeCustomerId));
        $chargeID = $charge->id;
        $success = 'Your payment was successful: '.$chargeID;
        //echo $success;
        show__paymentDone();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $error = $e->getMessage();

        show__errorPayment($error);

    }

}
```

It's working fine, but if the customer exists the token is not used and if the user reload the page he will be charged again.

To me, this code looks fine but how could I prevent from charging multiple times a user?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way using `$_SESSION` before `if($_POST)`:

```
if( (isset($_SESSION['stripe_token']) && ($_SESSION['stripe_token'] == $_POST['stripeToken']) ) {
        show__errorTokenTwice($token);
        exit;
}
```

After the charge is done:

```
$_SESSION['stripe_token'] = $_POST['stripeToken']
```